# Why is a finite sum calculated so long?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to compute the next sum:
[image]

It is calculated instantly. So I raise the number of points to 24^3 and it still works fast:
[image]

But when the number of points is 25^3 it's almost impossible to await the result! Moreover, there is a warning:
[image]

Why is it so time-consuming to calculate a finite sum? How can I get a precise answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
max=24;
Timing[N[
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,2,max},{j,1,max},{k,1,max}]+
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,1,1},{j,2,max},{k,1,max}]+
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,1,1},{j,1,1},{k,2,max}]]]
```

which quickly returns

```
{0.143978,14330.9}
```

and

```
max=25;
Timing[N[
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,2,max},{j,1,max},{k,1,max}]+
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,1,1},{j,2,max},{k,1,max}]+
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,1,1},{j,1,1},{k,2,max}]]]
```

which quickly returns

```
{0.156976,14636.6}
```

and even

```
max=50;
Timing[N[
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,2,max},{j,1,max},{k,1,max}]+
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,1,1},{j,2,max},{k,1,max}]+
  Sum[1/(E^((i^2+j^2+k^2-3)/500)-1),{i,1,1},{j,1,1},{k,2,max}]]]
```

which quickly returns

```
{1.36679,16932.5}
```

Changing your code in this way avoids doing hundreds or thousands of `If` tests that will almost always result in `True`. And it potentially uses symbolic algorithms to find those results instead of needing to add up each one of the individual values.

Compare those results and times if you replace `Sum` with `NSum` and if you replace `/500` with `*.002`

To try to guess why the times you see suddenly change as you increment the bound, other people have noticed in the past that it appears there are some hard coded bounds inside some of the numerical algorithms and when a range is small enough Mathematica will use one algorithm, but when the range is just large enough to exceed that bound then it will switch to another and potentially slower algorithm. It is difficult or impossible to know exactly why you see this change without being able to inspect the decisions being made inside the algorithms and nobody outside Wolfram gets to see that information.

To get a more precise numerical value you can change `N[...]` to `N[...,64]` or `N[...,256]` or eliminate the `N` entirely and get a large complicated exact numeric result.

Be cautious with this, check the results carefully to make certain that I have not made any mistakes. And some of this is just guesswork on my part.